# How to accelerate/decelerate stepper motor within loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, raspberry-pi

I am trying to accelerate or decelerate a movement from my stepper motor.

Im using this loop and from the `temporal` library:

```
var ramp = 50;
var i = 0;

var stepsToRamp = ((ramp * ramp) + ramp) / 2;

makeSteps(40, 5000);

function makeSteps(pin, steps) {
    rpio.open(pin, rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.LOW);

    temporal.loop(1, function () {
        if (i == 0) {
            rpio.write(pin, this.called % 2 === 0 ? rpio.HIGH : rpio.LOW)

            if ((this.called / 2) > steps) {
                this.stop();
            }


            if (((this.called / 2) < (steps - stepsToRamp)) && ramp != 0) {
                ramp = ramp - 1;
                i = ramp;
            }else if((this.called / 2) > (steps - stepsToRamp)){
                console.log("HERE I SHOULD DERAMP!");
                ramp = ramp + 1;
                i = ramp;
            }
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    });
}
```

This does work so far but it feels like this would not be a linear acceleration. The beginning is very slow and towards full speed (each iteration of the loop = one `HIGH` or `LOW` signal) it accelerates really fast. The same when decelerating.

Could somebody please help me here and show me where my thought process is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many steps does have that motor? Are you using any kind of special board or you are wiring it directly to the RPi (through a driver)

Comment: Yes Im wiring it directly to the RPi troough a driver. It has 200 steps per rotation but I'm using it in 16th step mode currently.

Comment: Are you sure you are following the right I/O pattern for stepping? I would split the problem into different pieces and create a function called PerformStep() or similar. Then, are you sure that your motor+driver are able to perform the steps in the given time? (The step time shorter than the loop time?) I think I understand your loop, but, could you please clarify the behaviour in pseudo-code?

Comment: The step is performed basically in one line: `rpio.write(pin, this.called % 2 === 0 ? rpio.HIGH : rpio.LOW)` and for a continuous moving I need some sort of loop. `temporal` is a very accurate timing library for robotics which does not use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. The movement also is pretty smooth and accurate. Im just looking for a solution for accelerating and decelerating now. My approach seems very "hacky" in my opinion and does not work like intended. Note that I can not change the `temporal`API which I'd like to use. Arduino would solve this problem but is rather not an option.

Comment: All right, I guess that what you are trying to do is some kind of simulated PWM modulation in a complex manner. First of all, for clarity, I would create an additional variable for acceleration, and not using "ramp" (bad practice), being this a constant used for configuring the script; then  for optimizing the loop execution time, I would put "this.called/2" inside a variable, so that way you ensure it is calculated only once. Non-liniarities are often caused by a wrong timing speculation: this is that sometimes the loop execution time is higher than the supposed loop time.

Comment: Despite the library is accurate, the content has to be executed anyway, and in case of taking longer than the loop time, then the next iteration could be delayed or ignored. Idem for "(steps - stepsToRamp)", you can create a variable, initialized before the loop and save computational cost, and also for clarity. But I think that the source of the non-linearity is that once you start accelerating, probably, the instruction rpio.write is not that fast as you expect, and this limits the execution of your loop.

Comment: Okay I will take all your recommendations into account. But I think it is more a mathematical problem. The `write` to the GPIO in this form is clearly functioning. Even if I put `0.01` ms as a parameter into `loop()` the motor moves clearly about 100x faster. So I don't think it is not fast enough. The problem lies more within this `ramp - 1` because imagine it taking 25 steps (bc I have `ramp = 50`) to become twice as fast at the beginning but at the end of the accel. it only takes 1 step to double it's speed. I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: This is because you have don't have a constant acceleration. I think you need an additional condition, of accelerating every fixed amount of ms. In your loop you are accelerating more and more often, so you don't have a constant acceleration, but a variable one. What about changing "i" out of the main "if" structure and updating "i" every "(i % ramp)"?